# UITableViewCell button to expand text in a cell - how to do this?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I've got a `UITableView` with a list of 10 sections, each containing a `textLabel`.

I've limited the amount of text in each cell to 10 lines and put a button to allow to user to expand the text in the cell.

The problem is, I want to change the text on the button when it's clicked between "show more" (if cell is not expanded) and "show less" (if cell is expanded). How can I do that?

Right now I have this code in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. It doesnt seem to work correct, sometimes the button displays "show less" when there are only 10 lines displayed.

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ButtonCell"];

if (!cell) {

  UIButton *readmoreButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

    [readmoreButton setTitle:@"Read More" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  [cell addSubview:readmoreButton];

}
else {

  NSEnumerator *e = [cell.subviews objectEnumerator];
  id object;
  while (object = [e nextObject]) {
    if ([object class]==UIButton.class && [((UIButton*)object).titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Read Less"])
      ((UIButton*)object).titleLabel.text = @"Read More";
    }
}
```

The following method is called when the user clicks the button. The `NSMutableArray` `ProposalInfo` keeps track of which cell is/is not expanded.

```
- (void)toggleFullProposal:(id) sender {

// get cell
NSIndexPath *index = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:(UITableViewCell *)[sender superview]];

ProposalInfo *proposalInfo = [self.proposalInfoArray objectAtIndex:index.section];

if ([proposalInfo expanded]==YES) {

    [proposalInfo setExpanded:NO];

    [(UIButton *)sender setTitle:@"Read More" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}  else {

    [proposalInfo setExpanded:YES];

    [(UIButton *)sender setTitle:@"Read Less" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}

// create index paths to reload
NSMutableArray *indexPathsToReload = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[indexPathsToReload addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:index.section]];

// refresh
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPathsToReload withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];

}
```

Comment: If I wanted such custom control I would subclass UITableViewCell

Comment: You will need to subclass and so it gets easier. See my example below.

Comment: Your sample code needs fixing.  Is this code working at all?  For instance in the first method you posted (`cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, according to your post) you are trying to add a button subview to a cell that does not exist (The variable `cell` is `nil` at that point).

Comment: Sorry I did not post all the code here, yes its working

Answer (score 0):

When the button is clicked make sure that now you set the full text to the cell. And then only reload the cell and mind it you need to fix the height of label in `layoutSubviews:` and then return appropriate height for `heightForRowAtIndexPath:` as well.

`((MyCell*)[tableview cellForRowAtIndexPath:buttonClickedindexPath]).fullText = myModel.fullText;`

and in the `layoutSubviews`: method of the custom class cell expand the frame of the the label so as to fit the text inside, then return the appropriate height in `heightForRowAtIndexPath:` and that should do the trick.

Comment: I actually have some code already that changes the text inside the cell (i just didnt post it) and also sets the height, using a datastructure to store the text rather than a custom class. I thought the advantage would be to save memory, because if u make a custom class you can't use [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier] ??

Comment: Why not ? It is called. It is the similar concept. So, try with the custom cell and and assign different cell with different object in init methods. And try to publish the something each time cellForRowAtIndexPath: is called and you will see the effect of cell being reused.